# Is this an antipattern: Next primary key stored in table

Tags: sql, design-patterns, documentation

I am looking for some sort of documentation on why this is (or is not) a poor design.

A 3rd party vedor's code uses a separate table to store the primary key of all tables.

```
__KeyTable____
NextKey  TableName
45       Table1
1003     Table2
90       Table3

__Table1____
id  Column1  Column2
45  ...      ...

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,        /* <---- IDENTITY(1,1) is not present */
    [Column1] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Column2] [nvarchar](1) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WFDATASET] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)
```

So when a new record is inserted into Table1, KeyTable is queried, the number 45 is found, 1 is added to that (in C# on a different server). The number is used in the next insert statement of Table1 then KeyTable's Table1 record is updated to 46.

This also prevents the ability to use cascading deletes. Instead every table has around 3 triggers which duplicate the effect of a cascading delete. It's an ugly design, I'm looking for some official article I can point at to explain why this is a terrible design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's a terrible design because you need to lock a row in KeyTable for the duration of your transaction against Table1. That is, while you're running the transaction:

1. Fetch the value from KeyTable
2. Store the incremented value in KeyTable
3. Insert a new row in Table1

No concurrent session can be doing the same. This is a big penalty for scalability, because all your sessions that insert to Table1 are forced to queue up and access KeyTable serially.

Whereas any well-implemented identity feature should only need to lock the identity-allocator very briefly, improving throughput. This happens in memory. IDENTITY caches a set of the next 10 identity values, and sessions that insert rows draw from this set.

Using IDENTITY should reduce contention for locks on the storage engine level too, which would be required while writing the changes in KeyTable back to disk.

Comment: Thank you that is well stated (and very helpful), I'm looking for an MSDN article or a thedailywtf.com type of anti-pattern that I can point to.

Answer (score 1):

A side-effect of using IDENTITY and its workalikes is that gaps in the sequence of values might happen. This is not a bug; it's by design.

But some applications require that you account for every ID number you use. Think about financial management systems, where you might need to account for every invoice number or every check number from the beginning of time to the end of time.  Using a key table, like the one in your example, is one way of guaranteeing there are no gaps in the sequence of values.

Another possibility is that your application grew up from an older, simpler system that wasn't based on a SQL dbms. (And so didn't *have* anything like IDENTITY.)

The only straightforward reason I can think of that *your* application would allow deleting rows (which might introduce a gap) without also using ON DELETE CASCADE would be that your tables don't have foreign keys.  There's no technical conflict between using a key table and using foreign keys declared with ON DELETE CASCADE.  (Try it.)

One rule of thumb for database designers is "Don't replace DDL with procedural code," which would mean that you wouldn't normally write three triggers on each table when you could just declare the foreign keys as ON DELETE CASCADE.  There are rare exceptions; chances are this isn't one of them.

Comment: I appreciate your input as well. And you are correct this was not pre-database the oldest version was written in ASP.Net nor is this written by-design just terrible code. Do you know of any MSDN article or a thedailywtf.com type of anti-pattern that I can point to?

Comment: I don't think it *is* an anti-pattern. If you need a sequence with no gaps, you have to implement *something* like this. Now, this might be a bad design for your application, but that doesn't make it an anti-pattern. That makes it a [WAD](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/W/working-as-designed.html).

Comment: The GAP problem is not addressed. The external id's which are displayed to the user get generated on a mouseover via ajax (you read that correctly) and if they are not used after 24 hours they are deleted with 4 xml files that were also generated (you read that correctly). This guarantees that gaps always exist. The majority of the tables are for other id's which are never displayed to the user. On top of all of this mess, the key's also store the file path to the xml file (you read that correctly) of the last used month for the table: Table1.Month.3. "Workflow maker" is a terrible product

Comment: Ah. You should have [identified the product](http://www.reddit.com/search?q=workflow+maker).